# pandas - plot sorted column to increasing integer index

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a pandas series with numerical values. What's the shortest way to plot the sorted series against an increasing integer index?

The plot should show:

x-axis: 0,1,2,3,4,...

y-axis: the sorted values of the series.

(please notice that I cannot plot it against the series' index, because the index is not necessarily an increasing index. In my case it's some id that I use for different reasons)

Thanks

Comment: Plotting with `use_index=False` is the cleanest and fastest.  That answer by paulperry needs more votes...

Comment: done, it was indeed the cleanest so far

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will first sort the series and then plot, ignoring the index of the series:

`ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=100))
ts.sort_values().plot(use_index=False)`

Answer (score 4):

Quick and easy: You can add a column with increasing integers and use this as x-values:

```
# some dataframe df
df['int_index'] = range(len(df))

df.plot(x='int_index', y='sorted_values')
```

If you don't want to keep the index, drop it afterwards:

```
df.drop('int_index', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

**Helper function:**

The Pandas `plot` function does not take "external" data as indices. You can  use matplotlib directly to plot as tnknepp showed, or keep the Pandas plotting (and formatting) with a helper function:

```
def plot_sorted(series, **kwargs):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'data': series}).reset_index(drop=True)
    df.plot(**kwargs)
```

Using a wrapper like this you can quickly plot any `Series` and customize the plot by calling with the appropriate arguments that will be used to call the `plot` method. Examples:

```
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=100))
# default pandas plot (with integer indices)
plot_sorted(ts)

# scatter plot (using `data` for x and y)
plot_sorted(ts, x='data', y='data', kind="scatter")
```

[image: Default plot]
[image: Scatter plot]

Comment: Thanks, actually I was hoping for something even shorter...
For example, normally the 'df' variable that you use, would be in my "playground" a very long line of different filterings of the main dataframe, which in the end has some different columns, and I want to check and see how one of them look against the integer number, then maybe another one and so forth.
So using your method, I would need at least 3 different actions for each time I want to plot (save a new variable, compute new index column, then drop it).. that makes things quite slow :/

Comment: @nivniv I updated the answer with a simple wrapper that allows you do view plots quick and without modifiying the original data.

Comment: @ninniv Plotting with `use_index=False` is the cleanest and fastest.  The other answer by paulperry needs your check, and more votes...

Comment: You dont have drop index, just use range(1,20) as x-axis as @tnknepp suggests

Answer (score 3):

For one line:

```
import pandas as pd
from pylab import *

fig = figure( figsize=(5,5) )
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)

# for Pandas version < 1.x
ax.plot( np.arange(df.shape[0]), df['A'].sort())

# for Pandas versions > 1.x (df["A"].sort is deprecated)
ax.plot( np.arange(df.shape[0]), df['A'].sort_values())
```

This is assuming your dataframe is called df and you want to plot the data stored in column "A".